# Textview below an image linearlayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to display a textview to the right of the image and another textview below the image.
But I am getting the following output:

This I am getting in the landscape mode:

ImageView   Imageview textview
                      textview

In the portrait mode the textview besides the imageview is not visible at all

Imageview Imageview
                   textview

Desired output:

Imageview  Imageview textview
           textview

xml

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dialogimage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="3dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dialog_image"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/dialog_image" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profimage"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/member_80" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/membervotes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/votes_bg"
            android:text="388"
            android:textColor="#343434"
            android:textSize="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="33dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/profimage"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="By Hermoine - 2 days ago on Politics"
            android:textColor="#040404"
            android:textSize="8dp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:typeface="sans" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Thanks,

Comment: use a relative layout and place the textview relative to the image position

Comment: Try changing first imageview to `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

Comment: can u elaborate please?

Comment: @Raghunandan i tried your suggestions and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want:
Image Image Text
      Text

You could create another linear layout with a vertical orientation to hold the image and text below it.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/dialogimage"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="3dp" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/dialog_image" />
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/dialogimage2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profimage"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/member_80" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/membervotes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/votes_bg"
        android:text="388"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="33dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/profimage"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="By Hermoine - 2 days ago on Politics"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:textSize="8dp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:typeface="sans" />
</LinearLayout>
```